# Getting words Starting with symbol in dart

Tags: regex, string, dart, symbols

I'm trying to parse in Dart long strings containing hashtags, so far I tried various combinations with regexp but I cannot find the right use.

My code is

```
String mytestString = "#one #two, #three#FOur,#five";
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r"/(^|\s)#\w+/g");

print(regExp.allMatches(mytestString).toString());
```

The desidered output would be a list of hahstags

```
#one #two #three #FOur #five
```

Thankyou in advance

Comment: Just use `#\w+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use a regex literal inside a string literal, or backslashes and flags will become part of the regex *pattern*. Also, omit the left-hand boundary pattern (that matches start of string or whitespace) if you need to match `#` followed with 1+ word chars in any context.

Use

```
String mytestString = "#one #two, #three#FOur,#five";
final regExp = new RegExp(r"#\w+");
Iterable<String> matches = regExp.allMatches(mytestString).map((m) => m[0]);
print(matches);
```

Output: `(#one, #two, #three, #FOur, #five)`

Answer (score 1):

```
String mytestString = "#one #two, #three#FOur,#five";
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r"/(#\w+)/g");

print(regExp.allMatches(mytestString).toString());
```

This should match all of the hashtags, placing them into capture groups for you to later use.

Comment: To get the matches only you can omit the capturing group